# Why is the intermediate value theorem a consequence of completeness and not just continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Spivak saves the proof of the intermediate value theorem for his chapter on supremums and infemums.

His proof makes clear use of the completeness of reals, but why I struggle to see why it is dependent on completeness and not just continuity.

Comment: On the rational numbers, the function $1_{x^2>2}$ is continuous.

Comment: Continuity can be used in many sets that are not the reals

Comment: @LutzL ah, yea there it is.  I was assuming that we were always considering the reals.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x) = x^2 - 2
$$
This function is continuous at every rational number $x$.
$$
f(0) = -2 \quad \text{and} \quad f(2) = +2.
$$
If the intermediate value theorem could be proved using only continuity, then we would conclude there is some rational number $x_0$ between $0$ and $2$ for which $f(x_0)=0$.  But there is none.